# Converting input containing special character to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the beginning of my program that calculates simple interest. Interest rate will have the following format : 0.97 , 0.67 , 0.17 etc. They won't be bigger than 1. So if the user enter 9 for the interest, program will convert it to 0.09 (by dividing it by 100) . Also user can enter input using '/'. So program will convert input like 97/100 to 0.97.

I wrote the code below. It works but it seems to me that there might be a easier and more elegant solution to this. Maybe using more build-in functions etc. If you help me with that I would be very appreciated.

```
def toNum(interest):

    if '/' not in interest:
        if float(interest) > 1:
            return float(interest)/100

        else:
            return float(interest)


    else:
        l= []
        n = 0
        count = 1

        list_interest=[]
        for e in interest:
            list_interest.append(e)

        for e in list_interest:

            if count == 1 or count == 3:
                l.append(e)
                count = count +1
                continue


            if e == '/':
                n = n + 1
                count = count +1
            else:
                l[n] = l[n] + e

        return int(l[0]) / int(l[1])






interest = input("Interest rate: ")






print(toNum(interest))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If your code is working, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be the place to ask for input.

Comment: I didn't know this site exists, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you've accomplished, and is reasonably compact.

**EDIT** added in a recursive function call, because I realised the if/else wasn't really necessary because you can just feed the numerator back in. This assumes, of course, that the numerator/denominator always uses 100 as its denominator.

It determines whether it's possible to `float` the input. If it can it either divides by 100 or returns, depending on whether the value is `> 1`. If an Exception is raised (in your case, meaning that the user has entered `"97/100"` or similar) it parses this out and returns the calculated rate.

There are a bunch of edge cases where this would fail, but it's something to build on/consider.

```
def toNum(interest):

    try:
        floated = float(interest)
        if floated > 1:
            rate = floated / 100
        elif floated < 1:
            rate = floated
        return rate
    except ValueError:
        return toNum(interest.split("/")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following might work:

```
import re
interest = re.sub('[^0-9.0-9]+', '', interest)
print(toNum(interest))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases, the input is purely numeric, or it is a fraction notation. So check if you have a fraction:

```
def toNum(user_input):
    if '/' in user_input:
        return abs(eval(user_input))

    if user_input.isnumeric():
        return int(user_input)/100

    raise AttributeError('`user_input` must be an integer 0-100 or fraction')
```

Since `isnumeric()` will return false if they input -1 or some garbage like that you're safe there.